# I can not run Substrate on M1

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

I could run Substrate before based on this advise. [Link](https://vikiival.medium.com/run-substrate-on-apple-m1-a2699743fae8)

cargo.toml

```
[patch.crates-io]
librocksdb-sys = { git = 
"https://github.com/hdevalence/rustrocksdb", branch = "master" }

[workspace]
 members = [
    'node',
    'pallets/*',
    'runtime',
]
[profile.release]
 panic = 'unwind'
```

cargo.lock

```
[[package]]
name = "libc"
version = "0.2.90"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum 
="ba4aede83fc3617411dc6993bc8c70919750c1c257c6ca6a502aed6e0e2394ae"
```

But I got another error again. Like

```
169 |                     (*cx.uc_mcontext).__ss.__rip as *const u8
    |                                            ^^^^^ unknown field
    |
    = note: available fields are: `__x`, `__fp`, `__lr`, `__sp`, `__pc` ... and 2 others

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0609`.
error: could not compile `wasmtime-runtime`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what changed that caused this? One first step if you are unsure is to `cargo clean`, update your toolchain `rustup update`, and then build from scratch again.

Comment: I changed "libc" package in cargo.lock file

[[package]]
name = "libc"
version = "0.2.90"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "ba4aede83fc3617411dc6993bc8c70919750c1c257c6ca6a502aed6e0e2394ae"

and I added this in cargo.toml file

[patch.crates-io]
librocksdb-sys = { git = "https://github.com/hdevalence/rust-rocksdb", branch = "master" }

Comment: Don't manually edit the lock file, instead update with `cargo update -p libc --precise 0.2.90`